# How to realize by pandas 'two sql result merge together '

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, addition

I have two dataframe like this:

A:

```
         pay  num
store                    
A001         医保   43
A001         微信   25
A001        支付宝    6
A001         现金   25
A001         通联    1
A002         医保   21
A002         微信   38
A002        支付宝   11
A002         现金   53
A003         医保   22
...
AC24         微信   29
AC24        支付宝   15
AC24         现金   51
AC3H         微信    7
AC3H         现金   15
```

B:

```
       pay  num
store          
A001    医保   43
A001    微信   25
A001   支付宝    6
A001    通联    1
A002    医保   21
A002    微信   38
A002   支付宝   11
A002    现金   53
A003    医保   22
...
AC24    微信   29
AC24   支付宝   15
AC24    现金   51
AC3H    微信    7
AC3H    现金   15
```

I  want  merge  A and B together by A.(store+pay)==B.(store+pay), A and B length don't same, use pandas how to realize this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need create `MultiIndex` by add `pay` to original `index` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and parameter `append=True`, then use [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) and last [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
a = A.set_index('pay', append=True)['num']
b = B.set_index('pay', append=True)['num']

df = a.add(b, fill_value=0).reset_index(level=1)
```